# Constructing a sequence $f_n$ for which $\|f_n-f_m\| = 1$ for all $n \ne m$.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $C[0,1]$ be the space of bounded continous functions equipped with the uniform norm. Let $\overline{B}(\overline{0},1)$, be the closed unit ball where $\overline{0}$ is the constant function. Construct a sequence $f_n \in \overline{B}(\overline{0},1)$ for which $\|f_n-f_m\| = 1$ for all $n \ne m$.

I'm not sure I understand the problem statement. They are asking me to construct some sequence of functions for which $\|f_n-f_m\| = 1$ holds, but how do I even begin to start constructing something like this? Essentially it seems that I want two sequences $f_n$ and $f_m$ whose distance is at most $1$ when the indexes are not equal? Is there some deeper meaning for this problem that I'm not seeing?

Comment: How is $\overline{B}(\overline{0},1)$ relevant here? Did you mean to say that $f_n\in\overline{B}(\overline{0},1)$ for all $n$?

Comment: Yup. I'll edit the question.

Comment: If you were to drop the continuity requirement, you could just choose any injective sequence $x_n \in [0, 1]$, and let $f_n(x_n) = 1$, but $f_n(x) = 0$ for $x \neq x_n$. Think about how you can make this example continuous, perhaps by using "spiky" piecewise linear functions instead of the above discontinuous examples. It may help to find a countable set of disjoint open intervals over which to make the spikes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Construct functions $f_n$ such $sup_{x\in[{1\over{n+1}},{1\over n}]}f_n(x)=1$, $f_n(x)=0,$ if $x$ is not an element of $({1\over{n+1}},{1\over n})$.

You can take $f_n({1\over{n+1}})=f_n({1\over n})=0$ and $f({1\over 2}({1\over n}+{1\over{n+1}}))=1$, $f_n$ is linear between${1\over {n+1}}$ and ${1\over 2}({1\over n}+{1\over{n+1}})$ and $f_n$ is linear between ${1\over 2}({1\over n}+{1\over{n+1}})$  and ${1\over n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f_{n}(x)=1$ for $x\in[1/(n+1),1]$ and $f_{n}(x)$ the straight line joining the points $(1/(n+1)-1/2^{n+2},0)$ and $(1/(n+1),1)$, and $f_{n}(x)=0$ for $x\in[0,1/(n+1)1-/2^{n+2}]$.

Answer (score 0):

Another example is obtained trying $f_n(x) = \cos(2^n\pi x)$.  For $n < m$ this is arranges that there is a point with $f_n(x) = -1$ and $f_m(x) = 1$, so that $\|f_n-f_m\| = 2$.  Then use $f_n/2$ if you really want norm $1$.